# First argument ”email“ must be a valid string Error

Tags: react-native, expo

This is the component/screen to sign in:

```
export const SignIn = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    
    return <ScreenContainer>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Welcome to my app!</Text>
        <TextInput 
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="example@gmail.com"
        keyboardType="email-address"
        placeholderTextColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        value={email}
        onChange={(email) => setEmail(email)}
        />

        <TextInput 
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="password"
        secureTextEntry
        placeholderTextColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)"
        value={password} onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Text 
            style={styles.buttonText}
            onPress={() => signIn(email, password)}>Sign In</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity 
        style={styles.buttonContainer}
        onPress={()=> navigation.push("CreateAccount")}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Create Account</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </ScreenContainer>
  };
```

This is the function to sign up form and auth user email and password using firebase :

```
const signIn = (email, password) => {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
}
```

When I try it I get this console message:

> createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string.

Not sure what's going on, would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

onChange return event

```
onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value) }
```

Another solution if you using react native textinput

Use onChangeText

```
onChangeText = {(email) => setEmail (email) }
```

Comment: Write to console, email password, and look at after send what's happening and what value included

Comment: it's undefined for email and password

Comment: Now check onChange functions write console and look at what's happening

Comment: How to do that?